# Bayesian interval significance test

Tags: intervals, bayesian

As far as I know, if a confidence interval of a parameter covers 0, then this parameter is said to be statistically insignificant at this level. I am wondering whether this is the case for a Bayesian interval. In other words, if a Bayesian interval of a parameter covers 0, then can this parameter said to be statistically insignificant?

Comment: This should be migrated to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: P.S. don't use "significance" in the Bayesian framework (I see fanatics coming your way). Also, the Bayesian framework speaks of "credibility intervals". Searching for that might help you out.

Comment: Am I allowed to do that? If so, how?

Comment: It will be migrated soon I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

In a Bayesian framework, you talk about posterior probabilities rather than significance.  So if an equal-tailed interval for a parameter is centred around positive values but still covers 0, then you can say there's over a 2.5% probability that the parameter isn't actually positive.